# How can I stream a MP3 from Amazon S3 using a UIWebView

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, uiwebview

I've spent the last few hours trying to figure this out and now it's time to appeal to some experts.

I recently changed my static file hosting to Amazon S3. As a result, when I try to stream my podcasts with my existing iOS code I get a "frame load interrupted" error. If I load the URL using Safari, it works fine.

Has anyone successfully streamed an MP3 file from Amazon S3 using a static hosting link (i.e. http://s3-us-west...)?

It appears that this fellow is seeing the same problem, with no solution either:

https://www.soundcloudcommunity.com/soundcloud/topics/uiwebview-frame-load-interrupted

I've also tried this and it's not working for me:

https://allforios.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/uiwebview-nuances-frame-load-interrupted-error/

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with ANY mp3s in a web view (I posted the one on soundcloud :p). This used to work just fine. Any luck?

Comment: The error is 102, which is WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange. I'm trying to look into what it means

Comment: I haven't figured this out yet, Jonathan. As a temporary workaround, I load the S3 URL using Safari instead of trying to host it inside my app. From a user experience perspective it's not ideal, but at least I can get the content out to my users. I'm surprised more people haven't seen this...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out for me that it only happens on the simulator. A device works fine :)